# Mathematical operations with atoms in prolog

Tags: prolog

If I have three atoms X, Y and Z where

```
X = 1
Y = 2
Z = +
```

How do I put them together so that X Z Y = 3?

Edit:
Using ThanosQR's univ solution, I have modified my code as follows:

```
% Parse list
parse_list([stop|_], _) :- !.   % stop predicate if element is "stop"
parse_list([X, Y|Z]) :- % go through the list line by line
    number(X, Number_1),
    number(Z, Number_2),
    operation(Y, Operation),
    Line =.. [Operation, Number_1, Number_2], 
    Result is Line,
    write(Result).

number(one, 1). 
operation(plus, +). % etc... etc...
```

I get false... Not sure why..

Comment: Please state your Prolog system (probably SWI) and the actual failing query.

Comment: You get false since the head of the second clause is incorrect. It surely should be `parse_list([X,Y,Z|Rest]) :-`. Also, the second clause has no recursion after the last write: `parse_list([Rest]).` That seems to be missing. Finally, the head of the first clause has two arguments, the head of the second has one. This is inconsistent!

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions. Thats a typo in the head of the first clause, it should be one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) operator:

```
R =.. [Z,X,Y], A is R.
```

Comment: Wow that's great, but when I use it in my code it returns false.

Comment: @chutsu does it work outside your code? what exactly are you doing in your code?

Comment: @chutsu just saw your edit, i think that twinterer spotted the problems; if you write [X,Y|Z] = L when L=[a,b,c] you will get X=a,Y=b, Z=[c], not Z=c

Answer (score 3):

First, a general remark: If you mix impure predicates like `write/1` into otherwise pure code, you end up with a very hard to debug program. So first try to identify the relation you are after. Maybe it is something like `tokens_meaning(Tokens,Meaning)` where `Tokens` it the list of tokens, as above, and `Meaning` is some expression to evaluate.

For identifying one problem, it suffices to look at the following fragment:

```
...
parse_list([X, Y|Z]) :- % go through the list line by line
    number(X, Number_1),
    number(Z, Number_2),
    ...

number(one, 1).
```

So what you expect here is that you have a term of the following form:

```
[one, Y|one]
```

That is, the `Z` should be the rest of the list. So either `[]` or something longer like `[_]` but not `one`.

But in your case you expect a name like `one`.  That certainly does not make sense. Probably you meant:

```
parse_list([X, Y, Z| Whatever]) :-
```

Comment: The reason I'm doing: parse_list([X, Y|Z]) is because I'm assuming the list will always have three elements [X, Y, Z]. And can you elaborate more on the pure code and unpure, am not too sure I understand what you mean by that.

Comment: @chutsu: It is still difficult for me to figure out what you actually want. `parse_list([X, Y, Z]) :- ...` might be what you want. But there are still too many things open.  Otherwise, please [refer to this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8305811/772868) for how a program with I/O and pure Prolog intertwined might become a cleaner program.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Turns out I failed to define one of the numbers in number/2 that is what caused the fail. Sorry for the headache I have caused you. And thanks very much for helping me on this matter.