# Steadfastness: Definition and its relation to logical purity and termination

Tags: prolog, logical-purity, non-termination, steadfastness

So far, I have always taken **steadfastness** in Prolog programs to mean:

> If, for a query `Q`, there is a subterm `S`, such that there is a term `T` that makes `?- S=T, Q.` **succeed** although `?- Q, S=T.` **fails**, then one of the predicates invoked by `Q` is **not** steadfast.

Intuitively, I thus took steadfastness to mean that we cannot use instantiations to "trick" a predicate into giving solutions that are otherwise not only never given, but **rejected**. Note the difference for nonterminating programs!

In particular, at least to me, [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) always *implied* steadfastness.

---

**Example**. To better understand the notion of steadfastness, consider an almost classical counterexample of this property that is frequently cited when introducing advanced students to operational aspects of Prolog, using a **wrong** definition of a relation between two integers and their maximum:

```
integer_integer_maximum(X, Y, Y) :-
        Y >= X,
        !.
integer_integer_maximum(X, _, X).
```

A glaring mistake in this—shall we say "*wavering*"—definition is, of course, that the following query **incorrectly** succeeds:

```
?- M = 0, integer_integer_maximum(0, 1, M).
M = 0. % wrong!
```

whereas exchanging the goals yields the correct answer:

```
?- integer_integer_maximum(0, 1, M), M = 0.
false.
```

A good **solution** of this problem is to rely on **pure** methods to describe the relation, using for example:

```
integer_integer_maximum(X, Y, M) :-
        M #= max(X, Y).
```

This works correctly in both cases, and can even be used in more situations:

```
?- integer_integer_maximum(0, 1, M), M = 0.
false.

?- M = 0, integer_integer_maximum(0, 1, M).
false.

| ?- X in 0..2, Y in 3..4, integer_integer_maximum(X, Y, M).
X in 0..2,
Y in 3..4,
M in 3..4 ? ;
no
```

---

Now the paper [***Coding Guidelines for Prolog***](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0911.2899.pdf) by Covington et al., co-authored by the very *inventor* of the notion, Richard O'Keefe, contains the following section:

> ### 5.1 Predicates must be steadfast.
>
> Any decent predicate must be “steadfast,” i.e., must work correctly if its output variable already happens to be instantiated to the output value (O’Keefe 1990).
>
> That is,
>
> ```
> ?- foo(X), X = x.
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> ?- foo(x).
> ```
>
> must succeed under exactly the same conditions and have the same side effects.
>   Failure to do so is only tolerable for auxiliary predicates whose call patterns are
>   strongly constrained by the main predicates.

Thus, the definition given in the cited paper is **considerably stricter** than what I stated above.

For example, consider the **pure** Prolog program:

```
nat(s(X)) :- nat(X).
nat(0).
```

Now we are in the following situation:

```
?- nat(0).
true.

?- nat(X), X = 0.
nontermination
```

This clearly violates the property of succeeding *under exactly the same conditions*, because one of the queries **no longer succeeds at all**.

Hence my question: Should we call the above program *not* steadfast? Please **justify** your answer with an explanation of the intention behind steadfastness and its **definition** in the available literature, its relation to [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) as well as relevant termination notions.

Comment: For the record:The term steadfastness appears in Prolog digest Vol.7, Issue 21 of 1987-10-02 written by Richard O'Keefe 1987-09-29 Subject: backwards correctness.

Comment: `integer_integer_maximum(0,0,M),M=0+0.` fails but `M=0+0, integer_integer_maximum(0,0,M).` succeeds in clpz and SWI:clpfd.

Answer (score 4):

In 'The craft of prolog' page 96 Richard O'Keef says 'we call the property of refusing to give wrong answers even when the query has an unexpected form (typically supplying values for what we normally think of as inputs*) steadfastness'

*I am not sure if this should be outputs. i.e. in your query `?- M = 0, integer_integer_maximum(0, 1, M). M = 0. % wrong!` M is used as an input but the clause has been designed for it to be an output.

In `nat(X), X = 0.`  we are using X as an output variable not an input variable, but it has not given a wrong answer, as it does not give any answer. So I think under that definition it could be steadfast.

A rule of thumb he gives is 'postpone output unification until after the cut.' Here we have not got a cut, but we still want to postpone the unification.

However I would have thought it would be sensible to have the base case first rather than the recursive case, so that `nat(X), X = 0.` would initially succeed .. but you would still have other problems..

Comment: s(X). Probably the first mentioning of this notion three years earlier is [here](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/PrologDigest/ALL). So we have now three different data points about that definition.

Comment: Add `.gz`. And: Warning: it's hughe