# what mistake in this medical diagnosis prolog?

Tags: prolog, medical

i am still new about prolog, i have a problem about a simple medical diagnosis program using a prolog, i try to find code about this medical diagnosis system to make it work, but i cant, i dont know what i need to change, i use SWI prolog software.

here the prolog code that i try use
it show error in domains,  show "syntax error= operator expected"

```
domains
disease,indication = symbol
Patient,name = string

predicates
hypothesis(string,disease)
symptom(name,indication)
response(char)
go
clauses

go :-
    write("What is the patient's name? "),
    readln(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write(Patient,"probably has ",Disease,"."),nl.
go :-
    write("Sorry, I don't seem to be able to"),nl,
    write("diagnose the disease."),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a fever (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a rash (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a headache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a runny_nose (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a cough (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a body_ache (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a chills (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sore_throat (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a sneezing (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.
symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write("Does ",Patient," have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?"),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).
hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).
hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).
hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).
hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

response(Reply) :-
    readchar(Reply),
    write(Reply),nl.
```

what i can do to make it working?

Comment: You are not using SWI-Prolog. You are using Turbo-, PDC, or Visual Prolog

Comment: SWI Prolog doesn't recognize Turbo/PDC/Visual Prolog syntax. Delete everything down to and including the line that says "clauses". Change the quotes on the strings from `"` to `'`. And `write` calls will have to chance since ISO `write` doesn't accept that many arguments. Then debug from there.

Comment: owh, i dont know that diferent between each prolog software... ok now i understand, thanks...

Comment: Generally, try to avoid side effects in the core of your programs. See [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8309945/772868)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the code was likely written for a logic programming language that shares features with Prolog but that's not considered a Prolog system (w.r.t to both official and de facto Prolog standards).

A quick rewrite of the code to get it running on SWI-Prolog is:

```
go :-
    write('What is the patient''s name? '),
    read(Patient),
    hypothesis(Patient,Disease),
    write_list([Patient,'probably has ',Disease,'.']),nl.

go :-
    write('Sorry, I don''t seem to be able to'),nl,
    write('diagnose the disease.'),nl.

symptom(Patient,fever) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a fever (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,rash) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a rash (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,headache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a headache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,runny_nose) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a runny_nose (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a conjunctivitis (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,cough) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a cough (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,body_ache) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a body_ache (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,chills) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a chills (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sore_throat) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sore_throat (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,sneezing) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a sneezing (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

symptom(Patient,swollen_glands) :-
    write_list(['Does ',Patient,' have a swollen_glands (y/n) ?']),
    response(Reply),
    Reply='y'.

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,german_measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,flu) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,conjunctivitis),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,cough).

hypothesis(Patient,common_cold) :-
    symptom(Patient,headache),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,sore_throat),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose),
    symptom(Patient,chills).

hypothesis(Patient,mumps) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,swollen_glands).

hypothesis(Patient,chicken_pox) :-
    symptom(Patient,fever),
    symptom(Patient,chills),
    symptom(Patient,body_ache),
    symptom(Patient,rash).

hypothesis(Patient,measles) :-
    symptom(Patient,cough),
    symptom(Patient,sneezing),
    symptom(Patient,runny_nose).

write_list([]).
write_list([Term| Terms]) :-
    write(Term),
    write_list(Terms).

response(Reply) :-
    get_single_char(Code),
    put_code(Code), nl,
    char_code(Reply, Code).
```

for convenience, this rewrite makes use of SWI-Prolog specific built-in predicate, [`get_single_char/1`](http://swi-prolog.org/search?for=get_single_char%2F1). You will need to replace its call if you want to adapt the code to run on other Prolog systems.

Comment: Why `get_single_char/1`?

Comment: As explained in its documentation, "this predicate does not wait for a return", which makes it handy for this use case, avoiding the need of typing a period and hitting return for every reply.

Comment: OK, thanks.  That's why I put a link to the documentation that does not state this ...