# Prolog Returning Elements Within Facts to The User

Tags: prolog

I have a Prolog knowledge base with some "symptom" facts called facts.pl.  Here is an example of my KB:

```
symptom("Typhoid", "muscle_pain").
symptom("Typhoid", "bloating").
symptom("Meningitis", "headache").
symptom("Meningitis", "fever").
symptom("Meningitis", "stiff neck" ).
symptom("Measles", "cough").
symptom("Measles", "runny_nose").
```

I have written a short prolog program in another file called "diseaseSearch.pl".  This program consults facts.pl and is supposed to allow the user to enter a disease name and prints the disease's corresponding symptoms to the screen.

My code:

```
:- write('loading disease database'), nl.
:- [facts].
:- write('disease database loaded'), nl, nl.

getsymptoms:-
    write('>   Enter a diseae name followed by a period.'), nl,
    write('For Example: Measles'), nl,
    write('Disease Name?:'),
    read(Input), nl,
    symptom(Input,Output),
    write(Output).
```

If I enter "Measles." the output should be "cough" and "runny_nose".  However, with the code above no matter which disease I enter it always returns the result from the first fact which is "muscle_pain". [SWI output found here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U1A8.png)

I found a similar method from an online tutorial, I am trying to learn the basics of Prolog input and output right now.  Am I on the right track? Some tips to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you really enter "Measles"? Or do you enter Measles without the quotation marks?

Comment: Measles. without the quotation marks.  Is there a better way I could annotate that to make it more clear? (I also have an image attached to show how it should be entered to the program).

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8309945/772868).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are entering Measles without " " and prolog takes it as a variables. Either you should enter it with "". If you enter Measles then it's a variables but if you enter "Measles" then it's a term.

If you want to enter without annotations then you need to make a database in which you have all terms(means that they start with small letter) then you don't need annotation.

Comment: Rather use single quotes instead.

Comment: I can't believe I did not think to try that.  That worked, thank you!